# Quartz: setting cron expression to run on the 1st and Last day of month

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

Quartz documentation gives an example for running a cron job on the last day of every month, like this:

```
0 15 10 L * ?
```

Fire at 10:15am on the last day of every month

However, I'd like to run a cron job on the 1st AND Last day of the month.
I would expect the cron would look somthing like this:

```
0 15 10 1,L * ?
```

But this syntax is not valid by quartz.

I couldn't find any proper/similar example in their [tutorial](http://quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.1.x/tutorials/crontrigger). Any suggestions?

Comment: It seems a bug in Quartz because documentation says nothing about using L and commas to list days. Have you tried to use `L,1` instead of `1,L`?

Comment: In the documentation link :http://quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.x/tutorials/crontrigger.  They mention - "When using the 'L' option, it is important not to specify lists, or ranges of values, as you'll get confusing/unexpected results." Probably you will have to setup two triggers on the same job

Comment: @AbhishekAsh this comment in the documentation seems irrelevant to the question, as quartz clearly not supporting L with other values. It should have mention that rather than describing something ambiguous as "confusing/unexpected results".

Answer (score 4):

So after some digging in quartz code I found this:

```
// throw an exception if L is used with other days of the month
if(exprOn == DAY_OF_MONTH && expr.indexOf('L') != -1 && expr.length() > 1 && expr.contains(",")) {
    throw new ParseException("Support for specifying 'L' and 'LW' with other days of the month is not implemented", -1);
}
```

org.quartz.CronExpression (quartz 2.2.2).

It seems 'L' is not supported for day-of-month with other days of the month. Too bad it's not anywhere in their documentation :(

Comment: still not implemented?